# FindShortestPath with negative weights isn't working

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I have the following functions defined:

```
RandomTree[n_, opts:OptionsPattern[]] := 
TreeGraph[UndirectedEdge[RandomInteger[{1,#}], # + 1] & /@ Range[1, n - 1], opts]

RandomCycleTree[n_, opts:OptionsPattern[]] := Module[{tree, e},
tree = RandomTree[n];
e = RandomChoice[EdgeList[GraphComplement[tree]]];
GraphUnion[tree, Graph[{e}], opts]]

RandomCycleTreeWeighted[n_, opts:OptionsPattern[]] := 
RandomCycleTree[n, EdgeWeight -> RandomReal[{-1, 1}, n], opts]
```

If I execute:

```
FindShortestPath[RandomCycleTreeWeighted[10, 
VertexLabels -> "Name", ImagePadding -> 10], 3, 7]
```

it returns unevaluated. Can anyone reproduce this and explain why it is happening?

Note: I am using Mathematica 9. I also tried executing this in Mathematica 8.0 and it also didn't work.

Comment: The `RandomTree` function is from the documentation (up to minor variations). See the Applications section [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/TreeGraph.html)

Comment: Seems the problem is with the negative weights. I tried BellmanFord to no avail

Comment: @belisarius Yes. Putting EdgeWeight -> RandomReal[{0, 1}, n] works fine. Weird, since in the documentation it is claimed that the "BellmanFord" method option should support negative weights. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`FindShortestPath` works for your graphs with  `Method->"BellmanFord"` but ... your graphs should be Directed.

Bellman-Ford's algo works for graphs with negative edge weights, but only if they are free of negative weight *cycles*. Think of it as if you could get a -Infinity  path: if your graph is undirected, you can always get a -Infinity valued path by going again and again forth and back over the same edge.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: You can also try this:

Comment: `RandomTreeWeighted[n_, opts:OptionsPattern[]] := RandomTree[n, EdgeWeight -> RandomReal[{-1, 1}, n - 1], opts]`

Comment: Then `FindShortestPath[RandomTreeWeighted[10], 3, 7,Method -> "BellmanFord"]` also returns unevaluated. Please tell me if you can reproduce this too.

Comment: It should work, because there are no cycles now.

Comment: @becko No, probably I haven't explained it clearly. An undirected graph is never cycle-free because a->b->a is a cycle and is always possible

Comment: Oh, I thought you meant *simple* cycles. To sum up, `FindShortestPath` with `Method -> "BellmanFord"` will work with negative weights with a directed graph without negative weight cycles, and `FindShortestPath` with `Method -> "Dijkstra"` will work with positive weights only. For any other graphs it will not work.

Comment: That's too bad. I wanted to find the shortest *simple* path between two vertices in an undirected graph with negative weights.

Answer (score 2):

RandomCycleTreeWeighted may generate graphs with negative cycles, whose edge sum to a negative value, and there may not be a shortest path. See Wikipedia Bellman-Ford page [1].

[1] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm